# JS create blinking using classes and timeouts?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add and remove a class from multiple elements with some delays,
to create a "blinking/flickering animation". 
But I cannot wrap my head around a good method for that, so what is a better way to set it up as I tried?

I have two separate arrays. The values refers to data-attributes of HTML elements.

Example arrays:

```
first = [1, 3, 5, 7];
second = [2, 4, 6, 8];
```

Example HTML element:

```
<span class="item" data-item="2">Second Item</span>
```

If a condition is met (or lets say on a click event) I want to start the following sequence:

- To each item of array "first" a class "active" should be added.
- After 1 second the class "active" should be removed from each array "first" item.
- At the same time, each item of array "second" should be added the class "active".
- After 1 second (or overall actually 2 seconds),
  the "active" class should be removed from array "second" items,
  and added to array "first" items again.
  Then, again after 1 second, each single element (of first and second) will receive the class "active". So every item is now active.

In the moment I am using multiple setTimeout and .each calls, but I find this messy.

```
first = [1, 3, 5, 7];
second = [2, 4, 6, 8];

// directly set array "first" items to active
$.each(first, function(value) {
    $('.items').find('[data-item="' + value + '"]').addClass('active');
});

// after 1 second, remove class from "first" items, add class to "second" items
setTimeout(function() { 
    $.each(first, function(value) {
        $('.items').find('[data-item="' + value + '"]').removeClass('active');
    });
    $.each(second, function(value) {
        $('.items').find('[data-item="' + value + '"]').addClass('active');
    });
}, 1000);

// after 2 seconds, remove class from "second" items, add class to "first" items
setTimeout(function() { 
    $.each(second, function(value) {
        $('.items').find('[data-item="' + value + '"]').removeClass('active');
    });
    $.each(first, function(value) {
        $('.items').find('[data-item="' + value + '"]').addClass('active');
    });
}, 2000);

// after 3 seconds, add class to all items
setTimeout(function() { 
    $('.item').addClass('active');
}, 3000);
```

Comment: It's better to use `delay()` instead of `setTimeout()`.

Comment: Click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and create a [mcve] with relevant HTML and frameworks

Comment: Also you can use .index to get the numerical order of the thing

Comment: Are css animations not usable in your project ?

Comment: @RaekhVoid I could use css animations, no restriction here. Do you had in mind setting a delay via css?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp
You have the `animation-delay` property that you could change for each element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works

NOTE: I am using .index() in the first and data-item in the second to get the even/odd

```js
let on = true;
let tId = setInterval(function() {
  $(".item").each(function() {
    const $this = $(this);
    const even = $(this).index()%2===0;
    $this.toggleClass("active", (!even && on) || (even && !on))
  });
  on=!on
},1000)  

setTimeout(function() { 
  $(".item").addClass("active")
  clearInterval(tId); 
},5000);
```

```css
.active { color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="item" data-item="1">Item 1</span>
<span class="item" data-item="2">Item 2</span>
<span class="item" data-item="3">Item 3</span>
<span class="item" data-item="4">Item 4</span>
<span class="item" data-item="5">Item 5</span>
<span class="item" data-item="6">Item 6</span>
<span class="item" data-item="7">Item 7</span>
<span class="item" data-item="8">Item 8</span>
```

Vanilla JS

```js
let on = true;
let tId = setInterval(function() {
  [...document.querySelectorAll(".item")].forEach(item => {
    const even = item.getAttribute("data-item") % 2 === 0;
    item.classList.toggle("active", (!even && on) || (even && !on))
  });
  on = !on
}, 1000)

setTimeout(function() {
  [...document.querySelectorAll(".item")].forEach(item => item.classList.toggle("active", true));
  clearInterval(tId);
}, 5000);
```

```css
.active {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="item" data-item="1">Item 1</span>
<span class="item" data-item="2">Item 2</span>
<span class="item" data-item="3">Item 3</span>
<span class="item" data-item="4">Item 4</span>
<span class="item" data-item="5">Item 5</span>
<span class="item" data-item="6">Item 6</span>
<span class="item" data-item="7">Item 7</span>
<span class="item" data-item="8">Item 8</span>
```

Comment: Thank you for this nice solution, and also your vanilla JS edit. Before I could create a minimal example, you already posted your answer. Besides Bootstrap CSS Iam not using any other framework or library.

Comment: Thanks - I updated it a little to get rid of the else.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the (vanilla) solution below!

```js
const first = [1, 3, 5, 7];
const second = [2, 4, 6, 8];

//plain vanilla
function blinkAll() {
  //the function takes array as arguments, that need to be formatted like yours above
  Array.from(arguments).forEach((arr, idx) => {
    //use the index as a multiplier, to set the timer of a second from each other
    //check if the argument is actually an array
    if (Array.isArray(arr)) {
      //iterate over the array items
      arr.forEach(element => {
        //select item
        const item = document.querySelector(`span.item[data-item="${element}"`);
        setTimeout(() => blink(item, true, true), 1000 * idx);
      });
    }

  });

}

function blink(item, onoff, first) {
  //use classList and remove or add based upon onoff switch
  item.classList[(onoff ? 'add' : 'remove')]("active");

  //first time executing? Set up the timeouts to get desired result.
  if (first) {
    setTimeout(() => blink(item, false), 1000);
    setTimeout(() => blink(item, true, false), 2000);
  }
}

blinkAll(first, second);
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<span class="item" data-item="1">First Item</span>
<span class="item" data-item="2">Second Item</span>
<span class="item" data-item="3">Third Item</span>
<span class="item" data-item="4">Fourth Item</span>
<span class="item" data-item="5">Fifth Item</span>
<span class="item" data-item="6">Sixth Item</span>
<span class="item" data-item="7">Seventh Item</span>
<span class="item" data-item="8">Eight Item</span>
```

Comment: DRY - Don't repeat yourself

Comment: I've been wrestling with that, but you assume in your solution that no array is need, so you approach it with solution using modulo, which is neat. I'm going to write a second (more generic solution beneath this one). My solution is tailored to his coding. But thanks for the comment. Appreciate it.